# How many steps will it take to reach the wall?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a wall is 100 feet away and you step 2 feet, and then cut the length of your step in half each time you step. How many steps would it take to reach the wall?

Comment: That would probably depend on how much you cut the length of the step by. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: You won't reach the wall; $2+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots = 4$.

Comment: Lets assume that the step size stays constant at 2, but the distance to the wall is decreasing by half every step. In that case, it requires 6 steps (ending at 98, 47, 21.5, 8.75, 2.375, -0.8125). Incidentally, at best you would never reach further than 4 steps past the wall - assuming that the length contraction worked the same way on the other side.

Comment: @lordsoth consider answering?

Answer (score 2):

The wall is $100$ feet away from you.
You step forward two feet.
The wall is now $98$ feet away from you.
You divide the distance in half.

The wall is now $49$ feet away from you.
You step forward two feet.
The wall is now $47$ feet away from you.
You divide the distance in half.

The wall is now $23.5$ feet away from you.
You step forward two feet.
The wall is now $21.5$ feet away from you.
You divide the distance in half.

The wall is now $10.75$ feet away from you.
You step forward two feet.
The wall is now $8.75$ feet away from you.
You divide the distance in half.

The wall is now $4.375$ feet away from you.
You step forward two feet.
The wall is now $2.375$ feet away from you.
You divide the distance in half.

The wall is now $1.1875$ feet away from you.
You step forward two feet.
You have reached the wall.

That is a total of $12$ steps.

**Edit 1:** I see that the distance is cut in half **each time you step**. In this case, the total is $12/2=6$ steps.

**Edit 2:** If the distance of the step is cut in half, then we have the [Dichotomy Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes); you will never reach the wall.

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with Zeno's dichotomy paradox, but the geometric series is relevant.